# Force initial Google Drive sync with a non-empty folder?

Tags: google-drive

I upgraded my iMac with an SSD last night and restored from a Time Capsule backup. Everything is now working substantially zippier and overall better, with the exception of one thing: Google Drive refuses to continue to sync with the Google Drive folder that it'd been using before the upgrade, and I ultimately ended up having to just delete the folder and let it resync from scratch to get past its stubborn error (alternatively, I suppose I could've simply moved the contents, set the path to the now-empty folder, then moved them back).

Is there any way to get past this particular issue (for future reference), or is it something that Google put in place to ensure that a new user doesn't go and specify their root drive as the backup destination?

Answer (score 1):

A little difficult troubleshoot at this point but did you try this:

- Click the Google Drive icon and select "View unsyncable files"
- Click Retry all.

[Google maintains a list of solutions](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2565956) for most of the common sync errors. You might give that a read.

Comment: +1 for the resource. And no, wasn't able to click "Retry all" or any other options other than to sign on, change preferences, or exit. And of course, trying to sign on just led to the error about the folder not being empty.